# mount on-prem volumes into azure container instance

Tags: windows, azure, docker, containers, azure-container-instances

We are using container instances deployed with and arm-template (docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.containerinstance/containergroups?tabs=json) and want to mount an on-premises volume into this container, as our environment is now both on-prem and in Azure. The on-prem environment is windows. How can we do this?

Suggestions so far that we have been looking into:

- Mount a volume through the ARM-template. (Is this even possible with on-prem volumes?)
- Run container instances with priviliges to be able to mount later with commands. (seems to be able through docker desktop, but is it possible through container instances?)
- Use SMB-protocol to reach files on-prem

Which of these suggestions should be the best one/is possible? And is there another option that is better?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to consider couple of [limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-volume-azure-files#limitations) when mounting volume to Azure Container Instance:

- You can only mount Azure Files shares to Linux containers. Review more about the differences in feature support for Linux and Windows container groups in the overview.
- Azure file share volume mount requires the Linux container run as root .
- Azure File share volume mounts are limited to CIFS support.

Unfortunately there is no way to mount on-premise storage to Azure Container Instance.

It is possible to mount only following types of volumes into Azure Container Instances:

- [Azure Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-volume-azure-files)
- [emptyDir](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-volume-emptydir)
- [GitRepo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-volume-gitrepo)
- [secret](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-volume-secret)

You may try to sync your files from on-premise to Azure Storage Account File Share using [Azure File Sync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-create-file-share?toc=%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Ffile-sync%2Ftoc.json&tabs=azure-portal) and mount File Share to Container Instances.